# Why is this boolean comparison not working correctly?

Tags: java, debugging, netty

So I am working with Netty and am trying to get a simple client to connect to a server over TCP but am running into a very strange, unusual problem. I am trying to connect and whenever I do it connects and then the client disconnects. I debugged the client and came across this strange problem which you can see in the picture. In the ClientBootstrap class that Netty includes it closes the channel if success is set to true in the try/catch above it. As you can see in the debugging variables, the variable success is set to true yet it gets through the if statement above that only continues if success is false. How does this make sense? I have debugged it and success is set to true above the if statement and then it goes to the if statement after. If someone has an explanation that'd be great.

[image]

Comment: @Shahzeb That's a `!success`... so `success` should be `false`. Was there an `Exception`?

Comment: Try `System.out.println(success)` before `ch.close()`, maybe your IDE is debugging a different (older) version of your code, and the line that highlighted when debugging is wrong.

Comment: Is there something about that img that makes transferring the information it has impossible or less meaningful? Talk about hard to read...

Comment: Those that are familiar with the Eclispe debugging will understand it. You are really only looking at the code that is highlighted in green and the variable "success" with its value to the top right. Anyways, I'm not too sure what the issue is but that seems to be my problem. It was working at one point and then "magically" stopped. Im going to mess with the libraries and see if I can fix it

Comment: Please provide the source code with text, not with images.

Answer (score 2):

> In the ClientBootstrap class that Netty includes it closes the channel if success is set to true in the try/catch above it.

No it does not. That's because of the negation (`!`). The *boolean negation* returns `true` if the expression next to it is `false` and vice versa.

You state:

```
if(!success)
```

Now `success` is set to `true` only if your program reaches the last line of the `try` is reached. If not it means something went wrong - probably with the channel - and now you are going to close that problematic channel. So it does the opposite from what you want it to do.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The value of success is set to true. That means that "if(!success)" is only true when success = **false** which it doesn't. The statement doesn't set it to true. It's just a conditional statement. The variable _success_ is set to true the 2nd line above it. So this isnt even a valid answer. I think you're confused. @CommuSoft

Comment: Evidently the negation does not set the value of `success`. It is however hard to debug if you don't provide (a more extensive version) of the source code. Be careful with debuggers. Sometimes they run an older version of your program and thus highlight/analyze different code.

Comment: It's not code written by me. It was written by the developers of Netty which is the strange part because it's used by a lot of people and not a problem for others. It's on line 198: https://github.com/code4craft/netty-learning/blob/master/netty-3.7/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ClientBootstrap.java

Comment: @baseball435: restarting the debugger doesn't help. Sometimes debuggers tend to mix two sessions.

Comment: Yeah i know, I can't find any solution to this.